# enabling horizontal scrollBar in textView - Swift

Tags: swift, textview, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I'd like to print a list of names into a textView, but i need it to stay each name per line. The normal behavior for the listView is brake the text when it reaches the edge and i need the text passing through the edge showing the horizontal scrollBar to scroll.
Is there any code to do that? Or a hidden trick? 'cause just enabling the scroll option didn't do the job. Thanks!